# XPiNC in Notes sidebar without use of Composite App?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, xpinc

I seem to remember at Lotusphere 2011 discussion that there would be a way to deploy an XPiNC page to a sidebar widget without using a composite app. Is this possible with 8.5.3 clients? I need to be able to deploy the XPage via the widget catalog, and I cannot have a composite app tab appearing in the client. (I could use a composite app if the only UI would be in the sidebar panel).  Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need XPiNC (we use XP as sidebar through http with SSO) and why don't you want composite (I see no drawback to make simple composite interface in XP application)?

Comment: We need xpinc since the page must access a local nsf for each user. Would be ok using composite app if it does not open a tab outside of the sidebar, and if it could be deployed via widget catalog (which I don't think is possible)

Comment: what do you mean by opening a tab outside the sidebar? do you mean you get a tab in the main window after adding a component to the main window?

Comment: Yes, exactly - when I launch a DB which defaults to opening a composite app which includes an XPINC page in right sidebar,  the sidebar opens but a tab opens in main window. I want to be able to simply open the sidebar. I could not find any other way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to put an XPage in the sidebar without Composite Applications. What you need to do here is to go to File -> Preferences ->Widget Catalog and check the "Show widgets toolbar and My Widgets Panel". Now Open the XPage you want to create as a widget in XPiNC. In the toolbar, click on the "Configure a widget from the current context". Choose "Display as Panel" , click next and then the finish button. Your XPage should now display in the sidebar. Another way is to just click the "Display as Panel" button in the MyWidgets toolbar, this will also put your XPage in the sidebar. If you go to the MyWidgets sidebar Panel, you will be able to see your XPage Widget there and it is possible to export it as a widget to send to other users. Or use the widget catalog and deploy the widget to your users via a policy setting.

Comment: This does not work for me, in an 8.5.1 or 8.5.3 client. When selected, the toolbar "Configure a widget from the current context" returns an error that the context is not supported. Has this worked for you with Xpages in the client (not a remote page)?

Comment: This is now working, using the steps above. My problem was that I had a policy which restricted the ProviderID's and Extension Point ID's allowed for installing/creating new widgets. Removing these restrictions allowed the above steps to work.